# Array.Sort() not sorting correctly

Tags: c#, arrays

Starting out and can't figure this out this one. This code was built to make arrays and sort it by increasing order

```
        int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        string readLine = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] values = readLine.Split(' ');
        int[] intArray = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            intArray[i] = Convert.ToInt32(values[i]);
            Array.Sort(values);
            {
                Console.WriteLine(intArray[i]);
            }
```

If I enter these inputs:

12

60 80 100 40 40 0 70 60 90 100 40 0

It outputs this

```
60
0
100
100
40
40
40
60
60
70
80
90
```

Why does it output like this? It has already done half the job, but why is the first four integers like this. It also seems that a 0 has turned into a 60. If not for the odd 60 I would assume that it only sorts based on the first 2 digits of a number.

Would like to know what I did wrong here

Comment: why don't you just use [`OrderBy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=net-5.0)

Comment: @Liam I'll look into it

Comment: Isn't that a "caused by typo" question?

Comment: You´re not sorting your array of ints, but your array of strings. String-ordering is different from numerical ordering.

Comment: There's some structural issues with your code it seems. The sample you've provided would call `Array.Sort` n times. And you should definitely look into OrderBy as well as `List<int>` instead of arrays.

Answer (score 3):

You appear to be sorting the wrong array? Perhaps:

```cs
int[] intArray = new int[values.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
{
    intArray[i] = Convert.ToInt32(values[i]);
}
Array.Sort(intArray);
for (int i = 0; i < intArray.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(intArray[i]);
}
```

or perhaps more concicely:

```
int[] intArray = Array.ConvertAll(values, s => Convert.ToInt32(s));
Array.Sort(intArray);
for (int i = 0; i < intArray.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(intArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: I see my mistake now. Thanks a lot!